# Evaluating the sum $\sum_{j = 1}^p j\left(j^n - (j - 1)^n\right)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, summation

$$
\newcommand{\Prob}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
$$

(This is part of Exercise 9.4 in the book *Measure Theory, Probability and Stochastic Processes*, by Le Gall.)

I am trying to compute the expected value of the maximum of a random sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$, uniformly distributed on $\left\{ 1, 2, \dots, p \right\}$.

Call the maximum $M_n$. I have determined that

$$
\Prob(M_n = j) = \left(\frac{j}{p}\right)^n - \left(\frac{j - 1}{p}\right)^n
$$

and therefore

$$
\E[M_n] = \frac{1}{p^n}\sum_{j = 1}^p j\left(j^n - (j - 1)^n\right).
$$

I assume there is some combinatorial wizardry that can simplify the expectation, but I don't know how to do it.

I was looking at [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), but it doesn't seem obviously applicable.

Thanks.

Comment: Separate the sum into two sums and perform an index shift for the second one.

Comment: Mathematica code shows 



$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[M_n] 
=& \frac{p^{n+1}-H_{p-1}^{(-n)}}{p^n} 
\\

=& p^{-n} \left(\zeta (-n,p)+p^{n+1}-\zeta (-n)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[M_n]=&\frac{1}{p^n}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{p}j\left(j^{n}-(j-1)^{n}\right)\right]\\
=&\frac{1}{p^n}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{p}jj^{n}-\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\left(j+1\right)j^{n}\right]\\
=&\frac{1}{p^n}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{p}j^{n+1}-\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}j^{n+1}-\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}j^{n}\right]\\
=&\frac{1}{p^n}\left[p^{n+1}-\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}j^{n}\right]\\
=&p-\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)^n\end{align}$$

Comment: An easier way to arrive at the same conclusion: $$E[M_n]= \int_0^\infty P(M_n\geq t)dt$$

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Answer**

Using your expression for the probability:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(M_{n+1}=j\right)=\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{j-1}{p}\right)^{n+1}
$$

we get

$$
\mathbb{E}\left(M_{n}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{p}\left[p\cdot\mathbb{P}\left(M_{n+1}=j\right)-\left(\frac{j-1}{p}\right)^{n}\right]
$$

The sum of probability over all possible values equals $1$, so we get the final expression:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left(M_{n}\right)=p-\sum_{j=1}^{p}\left(\frac{j-1}{p}\right)^{n}
$$