# Show that $\lim_{p \to \infty}\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j = 0}^{p - 1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)^n = \frac{1}{n + 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

**Background:**

This came up during Exercise 9.4 of *Measure Theory, Probability and Stochastic Processes*, by Le Gall. (The question concern the maximum of a random sample from the uniform distribution on $\{1, 2, \dots, p\}$.)

I asked an earlier question about a different part of this same problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840616/evaluating-the-sum-sum-j-1p-j-leftjn-j-1n-right).

**Problem:**

Show that $\lim_{p \to \infty}\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j = 0}^{p - 1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)^n = \frac{1}{n + 1}$.

**My attempt:**

I've got almost nothing. This appears related to [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). If we rewrite

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j = 0}^{p - 1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)^n &= \frac{1}{p^{n + 1}}\sum_{j = 0}^{p - 1} j^n\\
&= \frac{1}{p^{n + 1}}\sum_{j = 1}^{p - 1} j^n
\end{align*}

then this is a bit clearer, but I have no idea which form is best, and how to approach this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ This is simply a Riemann sum

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)^n = \int_0^1x^ndx$$